# Determining supported host target features without a compiler

Tags: clang, llvm

In LLVM-based compilers like `rustc` and `clang`, [we can select a target cpu](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#target-cpu) or a list of supported target features, like `avx`.

I can list the supported target CPUs with e.g. `rustc -C target-cpu=help`, or `clang -print-supported-cpus`.

One of the special values is `native`, which selects the current CPU that `clang` or `rustc` is running on. But now I want to know the correct value to use for a different machine, where no compiler is installed, and cannot be installed for security reasons. How can I know what `target-cpu=native` would evaluate to on that machine?

I can look at the list of supported CPUs, and the codename of my CPU as published by the vendor, but I don’t trust that this works in all cases, I would much rather confirm this with a runtime check.

Concretely:

- Is there a reliable way to convert the output of e.g. `lscpu` into an LLVM target CPU name? Or if we can’t have the CPU name itself, how do the “flags” that `lscpu` lists translate to LLVM target-feature names?
- Alternatively, does there exist a tool, which is not itself a compiler, that would print the LLVM target CPU for the host it’s running on?

Comment: No answer, just a comment… if you can make a snapshop of the target's disk and run it as a virtual machine elsewhere, then you can install whatever you want, and it might be nice for other testing too.

Comment: @arnt If I would run a snapshot of that machine in a VM, the OS would see the VM’s CPU, not the CPU of the host machine that I’m looking for.

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario where specifying the code name as the target architecture would somehow be less reliable than running with `-march=native` on the target system, but if you really want the code for how it determines what the code name is you can find it here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/lib/Support/Host.cpp#L1181